# What are the differences between topology and wiring in 3d modeling?

Tags: modeling, topology

What are the differences between topology and wiring in 3d modeling? I have always been confused about these two concepts. Could you please help me explain them?

Answer (score 1):

Topology refers to the way in which the vertices, edges, and faces of a 3D mesh are arranged or connected to form the surface of an object. The topology of a mesh can have a significant impact on how the object looks, how well it deforms during animation, and how easy it is to work with. Good topology generally consists of evenly-spaced quads (four-sided polygons) that follow the contours of the object's surface, while bad topology can consist of irregular or unevenly-spaced triangles and n-gons (polygons with more than four sides), which can cause shading artifacts and make it difficult to edit or animate the mesh.

Wiring, on the other hand, typically refers to the way in which the vertices of a mesh are connected to each other using edges. This can include the placement of edges to define the shape of the object, the use of loops or rings of edges to control the deformation of the mesh during animation, and the way in which edges are beveled or chamfered to create rounded corners or edges. This affects the way that light interacts with the model and creates its visual appearance. A well-designed wiring pattern will create a smooth and visually appealing surface for the model, while a poorly-designed wiring pattern can create visual artifacts like "seams" or "shading errors" on the surface. Wiring is often closely related to topology, as good topology typically requires good wiring to ensure that the edges of the mesh follow the contours of the object's surface in a logical and efficient way.

Comment: Erm... I have to ask... Did you copy/paste a ChatGPT response to write this answer ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AFjN.png You may want to read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned and https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy . I want to add that I think this is a good overall answer, albeit a bit *too* wordy for my taste. Cheers

Comment: I have a 3d modeller friend whom i asked and he encouraged me to share this. I'm not sure though if he copied it XD

Comment: Should I take it down?

Comment: Well I don't know :p I don't want to start a debate honestly, but I think we should be careful about using GPT answers verbatim on BSE. There is the risk of writing factually wrong answers that look right, but also as a user there is really no added value to going to the trouble of writing a question on BSE if you're just going to be met with an auto-generated GPT answer you could have gotten by yourself in the fraction of the time. I think you can add real value to this here for example by adding a few screenshots of a close up and far away view of a mesh demonstrating what the text is saying

Comment: By these definitions, it seems the wiring is a subset of topology. @Gorgious the problem predates GPT - I remember when I asked a [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/397938/36459) and got a factually wrong answer that I stumbled upon googling my question before asking it on SE. So the real problem is: answering by repeating, without applying some intellectual work like cross-checking with other sources, testing for yourself etc. which may end up spreading misinformation. Also: where images 

Comment: What's the difference between viewing a  polygonally-approximated surface as a set of [edges-between-faces] and viewing it as a set of [faces]? I don't get it. To me, they seem equivalent.

Comment: Yeah I just double checked with him and he said he copied it from Chat GPT haha, what do you reckon guys? I will delete it?